# Add the integers from double digit numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to add the integers from double digit number(triple etc.) together

> Block quote 22 = 2+2 = 4

I considered doing it manually but because I have 999 number to get through that'll take a really long time.

I tried making two separate lists and adding it together but continually received syntax errors.

*edited for extra detail *

Comment: Good for you. What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: To make what @MattDMo posted crystal clear, please **post your codes**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the integer to a string, and then sum the values up:

```
count = sum((int(digit) for digit in str(22)))
print(count)
```

This iterates over every digit, converts it back to an integer, and finally computes the sum over all digits.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm really tired right now or if my brain just isn't working properly but, i entered this into idle before fumbling around and messing with my code even more. If i enter this code into idle there's a huge indent and then if i enter a list into the blank space i repeatedly get syntax errors. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Try my edited version, I was missing a brace in the first version

Comment: it gives the syntax error : *multiple statements found while compiling a single statement*

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.5.1 edit: that's odd, i tried compiling it in pycharm and it worked! Thanks i really appreciate that my mind is really blanking out on me today.